# Which event observer is triggered when a wishlist is created or updated?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, magento-1, wishlist

I want to perform an action **whenever a wishlist is updated or created**, but I am not able to find that event. If anyone knows that event, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wishlist_save_before` or `wishlist_save_after` event.

Those events are dispatched whenever a wishlist is saved so it'll be triggered for both creation and update

Comment: Out of three answers, this is the right solution.

Comment: When I update wishlist from product page, it works but if I update from wishlist page it doesn't work. Why? Any Idea?

Comment: @GauravAgrawal those events are always triggered whenever a wishlist is saved. If that does not work when you update from wishlist page maybe it's because you did not make any change to the wishlist and thus, it is not being saved ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have updated its quantity but this event doesn't triggers.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal in that case it is not a wishlist update but a wishlist item update and you should use `wishlist_item_save_before` or `wishlist_item_save_after` ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Thanks to clear my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this event :

```
<wishlist_item_add_after>
    <observers>
        <wishlist_change_event>         
            <class>Your_Class_Name</class>
            <method>yourMethodName</method>           
        </wishlist_change_event>
    </observers>
</wishlist_item_add_after>
```

Comment: When I update wishlist from product page, it works but if I update from wishlist page it doesn't work. Why? Any Idea?

Comment: not sure but you can try this for update  :: wishlist_item_update_after OR wishlist_update_item

Answer (score 0):

Magento Core events to save and update Wishlist :

`wishlist_add_product` at `Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php` (line 212)

`wishlist_update_item` at `Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php`   (line 329)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below events for your purpose:

please check and try and let me know which work best for you

1) `wishlist_add_product`

2) `wishlist_update_item`

3) `wishlist_add_item`

4) `wishlist_product_add_after`

5) `wishlist_items_renewed`